# Backfilling a now replicated bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I asked this in the s3 forums to no response, so thought i would try here, my inclination is simply to go ahead.

Original question:

I have enabled cross region replication for buckets that have been around for about a year. I would like to get these buckets in sync, which i can do with the aws-cli, but realize they would not be true replicas of the other object for cross-region replication management. Is this a valid concern or should i just run:

`aws s3 sync s3://origin-bucket s3://replica-bucket --acl public-read` (public-read matches origin bucket)

and then let replication run as normal, the **only/main** concern is when a delete request comes along to the replicated bucket.

Btw i have about 5 buckets i want sync, 3 of them have significant data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question, just in case someone has a similar question.  I went ahead and ran `aws s3 sync` about a week ago and I move items out of the bucket and the two regions are staying in sync just fine, so ultimately syncing them was a fine solution.

If someone finds this and says that's crazy, great even more information to go off.